# How do you use for loop to find the minimum without using something similar to "min" on Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, minimum

This is what I have so far, but I would like to use it without min and with for loop:

```py
Numbers = [100, 97, 72, 83, 84, 78, 89, 84, 83, 75, 54, 98, 70, 88, 99, 69, 70, 79, 55, 82, 81, 75, 54, 82, 56, 73, 90, 100, 94, 89, 56, 64, 51, 72, 64, 94, 63, 82, 77, 68, 60, 93, 95, 60, 77, 78, 74, 67, 72, 99, 93, 79, 76, 86, 87, 74, 82]

for i in range(len(Numbers)):
       print(min(Numbers))
```

Comment: How would you do it in real life if you were given a set of cards with numbers written on them? How would you find the one with the smallest number?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another identical method is:

```
numbers = [100, 97, 72, 83, 84, 78, 89, 84, 83, 75, 54, 98, 70, 88, 99, 69, 70, 79, 55, 82, 81, 75, 54, 82, 56, 73, 90, 100, 94, 89, 56, 64, 51, 72, 64, 94, 63, 82, 77, 68, 60, 93, 95, 60, 77, 78, 74, 67, 72, 99, 93, 79, 76, 86, 87, 74, 82]

smallest = None
for x in range(len(numbers)):
    if (smallest == None or numbers[x] < smallest):
        smallest = numbers[x]
print(smallest)
```

Output:

```
51
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know *why* you do not want to use `min` (you should) - but if you do not want to you can loop over the numbers and keep track of the smallest.

```
min_ = None
for n in Numbers:
    if min_ is None or n < min_: 
        min_ = n
```

`min_` is now the minimum in the list `Numbers`.